# Extraer string html python sin lxml

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

estoy intentando extraer un valor dentro de html. Pero sé que para ello se necesita lxml y un compilador de clang, quiero saber si hay alguna manera. Ejemplo(viene de php)

```
"label":"Country","value":"', '"
```

Desconozco cómo,  no tengo datos para instalar el compilador de clang.

Comment: Hola mr-Z3rO, en principio no necesitas lxml, se puede haacer con Python estándar. (HTMLParser/html.parser). Por el ejemplo que pones no me queda muy claro si lo que recibes es html verdaderamente u otra cosa como JSON....

Comment: Si es Html, sólo que es javascript.